# Initalizing extended list in Python3.8 switch from value-type to reference-type when nested in dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

*Python 3.8.5 on Debian*

I've found an instance in which updating a single element in a list of a list of dictionary items actually updates all elements in the child list. It seems like this is a reference/value issue, but I'm unsure why this would change in the case of a list of dictionaries?

I understand initializing a list with a certain number of elements...

```
# Create list of 5 zeros 
ex_lst = [0] * 5
print(ex_lst) # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# Update first index of list 
ex_lst[0] = 42
print(ex_lst) # [42, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Doing the same thing inside a dictionary

```
# Create dict containing list of 5 zeros 
ex_dict = {
    'ex_lst': [0]*5
}
print(ex_dict) # {'ex_lst': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

# Update first index in list in dict
ex_dict['ex_lst'][0] = 42
print(ex_dict) # {'ex_lst': [42, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

But this is where it gets weird...

```
# Create dict containing child dict containing list of 5 zeros
ex_dict = {
    'chld_dict': [{
        'ex_lst': [0]
    }] * 5
}
print(ex_dict) # {'chld_dict': [{'ex_lst': [0]}, {'ex_lst': [0]}, {'ex_lst': [0]}, {'ex_lst': [0]}, {'ex_lst': [0]}]}

# Update first index of list in child dict in parent dict (updates all elements?)
ex_dict['chld_dict'][0]['ex_lst'][0] = 42
print(ex_dict) # {'chld_dict': [{'ex_lst': [42]}, {'ex_lst': [42]}, {'ex_lst': [42]}, {'ex_lst': [42]}, {'ex_lst': [42]}]}
```

Why do all elements in the list update when I'm only attempting to update the first? I understand Python doesn't really do by-object/by-value since "Everything is an object!". But I can't understand why this is the case.

I already got around this by using list comprehension in place of the '*' operator, I'm just curious if there's a reasoning behind it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python interprets {'ex_lst': [0]} as an object, and thus when trying to create five elements of this, it creates five elements with reference to the same object, which explains such behavior.
This also explains why using list comprehension would work, since you are creating new object each time when using list comprehension.
As mentioned in the comments by @Matthew Cox, We can observe this by looking at the id of the objects and verifying that they are equal: `id(ex_dict['chld_dict'][0]) == id(ex_dict['chld_dict'][1])` which returns True.

Comment: One way to observe this directly is to see that `id(ex_dict['chld_dict'][0]) == id(ex_dict['child_dict'][1])` is `True`

Comment: Yes @MatthewCox that's correct, thank you for the precision! I'll add that as an edit to my answer!

Comment: Thanks for the help, that makes much more sense! I have couple more questions if anyone's able to help: While I understand Python interpreting {'ex_lst': [0]} as an object, why does it create 5 elements with the same reference instead of separate copies? Is there an easy way to tell when Python is creating an object as a reference instead of a unique copy? Also is there some documentation somewhere that explains the object-reference system in more detail? It seems wherever I've looked people just say it's not something that exists/you have to worry about in Python...

Comment: I just found the .copy() function and with it relevant information about shallow and deep copies. That answers a lot of questions, but is this something I have to look out for in more circumstances? Or did I just stumble upon a really obscure use case?

Comment: I do believe the issue in your implementation is due to how * operation is defined for lists. I would recommend you try to understand [Pass by reference vs value in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/). It's true that it's not something you have to worry about, but it's something you should keep in mind in case you encounter the same problem again! Personnally, whenever I have a similar issue, i.e when I modify something it propagates all over the other objects, I know this is due to this, and I need to copy the object instead of passing it directly!